# Different signatures for **wafv2.CfnWebACL** interface in aws-cdk documentation and the one generated in ***waf2.generated.d.ts*** file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

```
import * as wafv2 from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-wafv2";
const wafAclCloudFront = new wafv2.CfnWebACL(scope,id,props)
```

The constructor signature for above

```
CfnWebACL.constructor(scope: constructs.Construct,id: string,props: CfnWebACLProps)
```

Where ***CfnWebACLProps*** are defined as shown below as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_waf.CfnWebACLProps.html

```
 const cfnWebACLProps: waf.CfnWebACLProps = {
  defaultAction: {
    type: 'type',
  },
  metricName: 'metricName',
  name: 'name',

  // the properties below are optional
  rules: [{
    priority: 123,
    ruleId: 'ruleId',

    // the properties below are optional
    action: {
      type: 'type',
    },
  }],
};
```

But then in my global ***waf2.generated.d.ts*** file, I see :

```
export interface CfnWebACLProps {
    /**
     * The action to perform if none of the `Rules` contained in the `WebACL` match.
     *
     * @link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webacl.html#cfn-wafv2-webacl-defaultaction
     */
    readonly defaultAction: CfnWebACL.DefaultActionProperty | cdk.IResolvable;
    /**
     * Specifies whether this is for an Amazon CloudFront distribution or for a regional application. A regional application can be an Application Load Balancer (ALB), an Amazon API Gateway REST API, or an AWS AppSync GraphQL API. Valid Values are `CLOUDFRONT` and `REGIONAL` .
     *
     * > For `CLOUDFRONT` , you must create your WAFv2 resources in the US East (N. Virginia) Region, `us-east-1` .
     *
     * For information about how to define the association of the web ACL with your resource, see `WebACLAssociation` .
     *
     * @link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webacl.html#cfn-wafv2-webacl-scope
     */
    readonly scope: string;
    /**
     * Defines and enables Amazon CloudWatch metrics and web request sample collection.
     *
     * @link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webacl.html#cfn-wafv2-webacl-visibilityconfig
     */
    readonly visibilityConfig: CfnWebACL.VisibilityConfigProperty | cdk.IResolvable;
    /**
     * Specifies how AWS WAF should handle `CAPTCHA` evaluations for rules that don't have their own `CaptchaConfig` settings. If you don't specify this, AWS WAF uses its default settings for `CaptchaConfig` .
     *
     * @link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webacl.html#cfn-wafv2-webacl-captchaconfig
     */
    readonly captchaConfig?: CfnWebACL.CaptchaConfigProperty | cdk.IResolvable;
    /**
     * A map of custom response keys and content bodies. When you create a rule with a block action, you can send a custom response to the web request. You define these for the web ACL, and then use them in the rules and default actions that you define in the web ACL.
     *
     * For information about customizing web requests and responses, see [Customizing web requests and responses in AWS WAF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-custom-request-response.html) in the [AWS WAF Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-chapter.html) .
     *
     * For information about the limits on count and size for custom request and response settings, see [AWS WAF quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/limits.html) in the [AWS WAF Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-chapter.html) .
     *
     * @link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webacl.html#cfn-wafv2-webacl-customresponsebodies
     */
    readonly customResponseBodies?: {
        [key: string]: (CfnWebACL.CustomResponseBodyProperty | cdk.IResolvable);
    } | cdk.IResolvable;
    /**
     * A description of the web ACL that helps with identification.
     *
     * @link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webacl.html#cfn-wafv2-webacl-description
     */
    readonly description?: string;
    /**
     * The name of the web ACL. You cannot change the name of a web ACL after you create it.
     *
     * @link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webacl.html#cfn-wafv2-webacl-name
     */
    readonly name?: string;
    /**
     * The rule statements used to identify the web requests that you want to allow, block, or count. Each rule includes one top-level statement that AWS WAF uses to identify matching web requests, and parameters that govern how AWS WAF handles them.
     *
     * @link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webacl.html#cfn-wafv2-webacl-rules
     */
    readonly rules?: Array<CfnWebACL.RuleProperty | cdk.IResolvable> | cdk.IResolvable;
    /**
     * Key:value pairs associated with an AWS resource. The key:value pair can be anything you define. Typically, the tag key represents a category (such as "environment") and the tag value represents a specific value within that category (such as "test," "development," or "production"). You can add up to 50 tags to each AWS resource.
     *
     * > To modify tags on existing resources, use the AWS WAF APIs or command line interface. With AWS CloudFormation , you can only add tags to AWS WAF resources during resource creation.
     *
     * @link http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-wafv2-webacl.html#cfn-wafv2-webacl-tags
     */
    readonly tags?: cdk.CfnTag[];
}
```

Why **interface CfnWebACLProps** differs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the documentation link in the question refers to `aws-waf`, and you're using `aws-wafv2`, which is different. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_wafv2.CfnWebACLProps.html)'s the documentation on `CfnWebACLProps` in `aws-wafv2`, which matches the generated code you're seeing.

Comment: So indeed we have two v2. Maybe they should have called it v3 !!

So confuse !!!

Comment: //aws-cdk-lib.aws_waf.CfnWebACLProps.html

Comment: // aws-cdk-lib.aws_wafv2.CfnWebACLProps.html

Comment: Both inside 

// https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2

Comment: They're both part of CDK, sure, with the latest version of CDK being 2. But they're different APIs - WAF Classic and WAF V2.